# Is there a sample implementation of Kiba ETL Job using s3 bucket with csv files as source and the destination is in s3 bucket also?

Tags: kiba-etl

I have csv file in s3 and I wanted to transform some columns and put the result in another s3 bucket and sometimes in same bucket but with different folder. Can I achieve it using Kiba? Im possible.. do I need to store the csv data in database first before transformation and other stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using Kiba! There is no such implementation sample available today. I'll provide vendor-supported S3 components as part of [Kiba Pro](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki#kiba-pro) in the future.

That said, what you have in mind is definitely possible (I've done this for some clients) - and there is definitely no need to store the CSV data in a database first.

What you need to do is implement a [Kiba S3 source](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Implementing-ETL-sources) and [destination](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Implementing-ETL-destinations) which will do that for you.

I recommend that you check out the [AWS Ruby SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby), and in particular the [S3 Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples.html).

The following links will be particularly helpful:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-get-bucket-items.html to list the bucket items
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-get-bucket-item.html to download the file locally before processing it
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-upload-bucket-item.html to upload a file back to S3

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it helped ! Can you please mark the answer as valid ? Thanks !